# how to add validation to is_array"

Tags: php

I am a newby on php and i am trying to figure out how I could add preg_match to my script.
Need some help.

This is what I would like to add: I have several of them

```
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name))
{
  $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
}
```

This is my script:

```
foreach ($_POST as $name => $wert) {
  if (is_array($wert)) {
    foreach ($wert as $einzelwert) {
      $mailtext .= $name.$trenner.$einzelwert."\n";
    }
  }  
  else {
    $mailtext .= $name.$trenner.$wert."\n";
  }
}
```

Would I have to add it just below and for each '$wert' seperatly?

Many thanks

Comment: OT: Using german in your code is not a good idea. For instance, it makes it hard to understand for non-german-speakers on StackOverflow. Bitte Ändern ;-)

Comment: Ok, will change to english.

Answer (score 0):

What you might want to do is write a function/method that validates your input. But only if all your inputs have the same validation rules.

An example of what you could do:

```
function validateInput($input) {
  if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name))
  {
    // handle error
  }
  else {
    return true;
  }
}

foreach ($_POST as $name => $wert) {
  if (is_array($wert)) {
    foreach ($wert as $einzelwert) {
      if (validateInput($einzelwert) === TRUE) {
        $mailtext .= $name.$trenner.$einzelwert."\n";
      }
    }
  }  
  elseif (validateInput($einzelwert)) {
    $mailtext .= $name.$trenner.$wert."\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andresch. So does this means it is not possible to validate if the inputs are having different rules'

Comment: @user3450822 you're welcome. Click the little arrow underneath the voting option on the left of my answer to accept the answer. That way it will be marked as solved.

Comment: @user3450822 Also, Yes, it is possible. Maybe you want to check out Validator Libaries and Tools such as the symfony2 validator: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html You could also define a map that matches inputs with rules. But i guess google has more information on that ;-)

Comment: sorry, but the input you gave me unfortunately didn't work. still looking for another solution. if the accept button means that I have read your comment, please let me know. will than tick it accepted again